# If $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$, $(I,x)$ is a maximal ideal in $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[Click Link to Original Text](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.uc.edu%2F~tsmith%2Fmath611%2Fpolynomial.pdf&ei=FblwVbKcMPOHsQSqooPQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHS0SemWHoUKvCAkbmfK2l6_rZspA)

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$.  Then, $(I) = I[x]$ is an ideal in $R[x]$.  I was able to prove, via first isomorphism, that $\frac{R[x]}{(I)}$ is isomomorphic to $\frac{R}{I}[x]$.  It follows that if $I$ is a prime ideal, then $(I)$ is a prime ideal in $R[x]$.

Then the author noted that, if $I$ is maximal, it does not mean that $(I) = I[x]$ is maximal.  If my understanding is correct, it is because while $R/I$ is a field, $\frac{R}{I}[x]$ may still only be an integral domain.  Finally, the author added that $(I, x)$ is a maximal ideal in $R[x]$.  What does the notation $(I, x)$ stand for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (sloppy) notation $(I,x)$ should mean the ideal generated by $I$ and $x$, that is
$$
(I,x)=IR[x]+xR[x]
$$
The quotient
$$
R[x]/(I,x)
$$
is isomorphic to $R/I$. Just consider the homomorphism
$$
R[x]\to R/I
$$
sending $r\in R$ to $r+I$ and $x$ to $0+I$.

Your intuition is correct: if $(I)=IR[x]=I[x]$, the quotient $R[x]/I[x]$ is isomorphic to $(R/I)[x]$ which is *never* a field.

Comment: TY for clarification.  You're right that $\frac{R}{I}[x]$ is not a field.  I forgot to consider the degree.

Comment: Could someone expand the notation $(I,x)=IR[x]+xR[x]$ abit more if $I=\{z,y\}$? would it be $ (I,x)=zR[x] + yR[x]+xR[x]$?

Comment: If $A$ is a subset of $R[x]$, then $(A)=AR[x]$, in the sense of the set consisting of sums of elements $af$, where $a\in A$ and $f\in R[x]$. In the case of $A\cup B$, we get $(A\cup B)=AR[x]+BR[x]$. In this case $A=I$ and $B=\{x\}$.

Comment: @egreg sir, Consider $I=(2,x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$,  $(I,y)=((2,x),y)$. Is $(I,y)=(2,x,y)$? I mean is $((2,x),y)=(2,x,y)$? Please reply...