# Ideal on polynomial ring generated by prime ideal on the original ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to prove that if $R$ is a communtative ring with unity and $I$ a prime ideal of $R$, then
$$J=(I,X)$$
is a prime ideal on $R[X]$

I know that the ideal generated by $I$ in $R[X]$ is prime but I don't know why $J$ should also be prime.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We have $R[X]/J\cong R/I$, which is an integral domain, because $I$ is prime. Hence $J$ is prime. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312528/if-i-is-a-maximal-ideal-in-r-i-x-is-a-maximal-ideal-in-rx).

Comment: Of course! Thanks!